# can you add a charfield to a list of checkboxes in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form with a list of checkboxes. 
If the user can't find what he wants, he should be able to check 'Other', and then fill in a text input, hit submit and the form will register the value of the input as choice.

Is there a way of escaping the pre-defined options found in forms.py?
When I change the value of the checkbox, it fails Django validation on submission.

These are the options in forms.py

```
INTEREST_DESTINATION_CHOICES = (
('cornwall', 'Cornwall'),
('cotswolds', 'Cotswolds'),
('east anglia', 'East Anglia'),
('Lake District', 'Lake District'),
('Devon', 'Devon'),
('Dorset', 'Dorset'),
('Peak District', 'Peak District'),
('Wales', 'Wales'),
('Sussex', 'Sussex'),
('Other', 'Other'),
)
```

This seems like a common feature for forms, but can't find anything about it online or in the docs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate field that is hidden and only shown and validated if "Other" option is selected. They way that you store that information and you send it to your model it does not make a difference since you are really storing strings.